# How to show the selected link by highlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is supposed to keep the selected link highlighted but it does not, it only flashes the green color on click. Please help me find out what failing here.

```css
#sidebarContent a:active{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContent">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Manage</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Links</a></li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a link on `href`, You need to set `foucs` to change color

```css
#sidebarContent a:active , #sidebarContent a:focus{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContent">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Manage</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Links</a></li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:hover` for highlight this:

```css
#sidebarContent a:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContent">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Manage</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Links</a></li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @P.Franks but I don't want the hover, I wanted the link to stay highlighted after the click on it .

Answer (score 1):

```css
#sidebarContent a:focus{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarContent">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Manage</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:10px"><a style="outline:none" href="#">Links</a></li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit your **css**. ie

```
<style>
    /* unvisited link */

    a:link {
        background-color: red;
    }

    /* visited link */

    a:visited {
        background-color: green;
    }

    /* mouse over link */

    a:hover {
        background-color: hotpink;
    }

    /* selected link */

    a:active {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```